# Do Not Display: To display the webpage again internet explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like not to dispaly the pop-up message below when post back occurs. My page has nothing to do with pricing it is displaying ms chart that updates on postback. How to disable in code or java script?

> to display the webpage again internet explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted.

This is the javascript i've tried: doesn't work though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <!--
function submitForm() {
    window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();
    }
// -->
</script>
```

and is attached the function to the form as so:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="submitForm()">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd bet you're doing this in your JavaScript:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

While the above code comes from the Facebook documentation, and it works for a standalone website implementing the Facebook JavaScript SDK, **it will break your Facebook App** in Internet Explorer and Firefox by causing an infinite loop.

When Facebook loads an App, it sends information about the user's authentication state via POST. The SDK processes this data and authenticates the user.

By telling the JavaScript SDK to reload the page upon successful authentication, Firefox and Internet Explorer interpret this to mean they should send the POST data again, too. Your App receives the POST data again, re-authenticates the user, and reloads the page, causing the infinite loop.

Solution: don't use `window.location.reload()`. Instead you'll need to set `window.location.href` (or otherwise strip the POST data from the browser request).

Comment: +1 I think you just saved me from tearing *ALL* of my hair out! :P  **Thanks a lot buddy** - this fixed my issue!

Comment: I'm new to js and am running into this.  I like what you wrote here but not sure how to implement.  Instead of using window.location.reload, I "set windows.location.href"?  Set it to what and/or do what with it?

Comment: I figured it out...for those like me that didn't understand...  window.location.href = window.location.href; worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those less fluent in Javascript like I am, I'll expound a bit on what Aaron said.  At least this is what I dug up after reading his post.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

this will replace the `document.location.reload();` and works as advertised.

I ended up having to modify the `window.location.href` string because my page behaved differently depending on what page the user came from.  So here's my complete method for posterity.

```
    function RefreshParentPage()
    {
        //document.location.reload();
        var redirectURL = window.location.href;

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("showpage=summary") > -1) {
            redirectURL = document.location.href.replace("showpage=summary", "showpage=events")
        }

        window.location.href = redirectURL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That means this page was obtained after doing a POST request. The best way to stop that is to redirect to the same page after having processed the POST request in your server code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In your ASP.NET code, after you're done processing the page and displaying charts and what not, redirect to the same page. In ASP.NET I think you could do `Response.Redirect("#")`

Comment: I added the follwing code to Page_Load but it doesn't keep the the changes to web page it reloads the original ' If Not IsPostBack Then Else Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) End If'

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the intricacies of ASP.NET. Someone else should be able to provide a good answer.